# ODBC Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\odbc_connect()

Tags: php, oracle, odbc, unixodbc

How do I get my php to talk an ORACLE db?

I have installed instantclient_11_2 & unixODBC

```
   # odbcinst -j
    unixODBC 2.3.1
    DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
    SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
    FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
    USER DATA SOURCES..: /root/.odbc.ini
    SQLULEN Size.......: 8
    SQLLEN Size........: 8
    SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

ODBC.ini is as follows

```
    [VASTUPROD]
    #Driver=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/libsqora.so.11.1
    Driver=Oracle11.2
    ServerName=//**.**.**.**/VASTUPROD
    Port=1521
    Database=VASTUPROD
```

odbcinst.ini is as follows

```
[Oracle11.2]
Description=Oracle ODBC Driver
Driver=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/libsqora.so.11.1
FileUsage=1
UsageCount=5
Trace=yes
TraceFile=/tmp/oracleDriver.log

[Oracle12.2]
Description=Oracle ODBC Driver
Driver=/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libsqora.so.12.1
FileUsage=1
UsageCount=1
Trace=yes
TraceFile=/tmp/oracleDriver.log
```

php.ini

```
extension=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/libsqora.so.11.1
```

php warning

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/libsqora.so.11.1' - libodbcinst.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

isql -v error

```
[IM002][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

Comment: Does the file `/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/libsqora.so.11.1` exist?

Comment: Yes the files exists.

Comment: And your output of `isql -v` is actually the output of `isql -v VASTUPROD`? Are all dependencies for libsqora.so.11.1 okay? What is the output of `ldd /usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/libsqora.so.11.1` / does it show any missing dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Add or enable `extension=php_odbc.dll` in php.ini file and restart your server.